# rails subdomain routing (both static and wildcard!)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Got a quick question about configuring proper routing for subdomains in `routes.rb`. I looked around Google and noticed there is not a lot of resources and definitive answers on subdomain routing.

This is the configuration for our application:

> 1. www.domain.com => root_path
> 2. api.domain.com => api controller
> 3. admin.domain.com => admin controller
> 4. *.domain.com => subdomain controller (only allows whitelisted
>      domains, ie: sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com, sub3.domain.com)

I imagine it would be constraints for subdomain `'www'` and `'api'` and `'admin'`, but would appreciate any further advice, thanks!!

Comment: I think, It should be managed at web server level as well.

Comment: Have you tried using a constraint like this? like `get '/users, to: 'users#index, constraints: { subdomain: 'www' }` .

Comment: Thanks Manish! How do you imagine the web server interacting with the application routing?